# Approximation of inverse of sum of matrices for stiffness matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have some partitioned global stiffness matrix $K_G$ such that $K_G^{-1} F=u$ for some force vector $F$ and resultant nodal displacements $u$. I'm interested in how the nodal displacements are effected as the stiffness of a single element changes. The new global stiffness matrix can be expressed as

$$K_G^*=K_G+\varepsilon K_e$$

Where $K_e$ is the stiffness matrix of some particular element and $\varepsilon$ is a constant controlling how much the stiffness of the element is changing. The new displacements, $u^*$, can be found from

$$u^*=(K_G+\varepsilon K_e)^{-1}F$$

So I'm interesting in finding an approximation for $(K_G+\varepsilon K_e)^{-1}$. Initially I used:

$$(K_G+\varepsilon K_e)^{-1}F=K_G^{-1}F-\varepsilon K_G^{-1}K_e K_G^{-1}F$$
$$u^*=u-\varepsilon K_G^{-1}K_e u$$

And this worked really well. I tested this against a simple structural model where I modified the stiffness of a single column and look at how the displacement of a nearby point changed.
[image: graph of displacement vs epsilon]
Black dashed line is displacement as predicted by the above equation, red crosses are actual displacements from structural analysis. I was then interested to see how good of a prediction this was, so I plotted the ratio of the change in displacement between the equation and the actual results. This resulted in:
[image: ratio of change in displacement between equation and structural analysis vs epsilon]
I was surprised to see it was an almost perfect straight line with the equation $r=\varepsilon+1$. I then created a "corrected" version of the previous equation that divides this ratio out, so:
$$u^*=u-\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} K_G^{-1}K_e u$$
This then makes the equation almost exactly match the structural analysis.
[image: correct equation for displacement vs epsilon]
The equation won't work for $\varepsilon=-1$ where the structural member is removed completely, which results in a very large but finite displacement, but it is a significantly better prediction than the original "uncorrected" equation. My problem is that I am not sure why this works. I have seen the Sherman-Morrison formula, which can be expressed as:
$$(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{1}{1+tr(BA^{-1})}A^{-1}BA^{-1}$$
Where $B$ is a matrix of rank 1. Replacing $B$ with $\varepsilon B$ in the above formula would give almost the equation I am looking for, but the $tr(BA^{-1})$ element would remain. It also does not work directly for my case since the rank of the element stiffness matrix is greater than 1 (in this case, 3). I'm looking for some way to demonstrate how the equation I found is a good approximation in general. I'm guessing the properties of the global stiffness matrix  and the element stiffness matrix will be needed, namely:

- $K_G$ is a positive definite matrix
- The rank of $K_G$ is significantly larger than the rank of $K_e$
- The rank of $K_e$ is close to but not equal to 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.